# Calculate and give all the answers of the following differential equation $y^2-x(y')^2=1$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The equation given is  $y^2-x(y')^2=1$.

I did this:

$y=+/-\sqrt{1+x(y')^2}$, and let $y'=u$

Now I only consider $y=+\sqrt{1+x(y')^2}$

$y=\sqrt{1+xu^2}$

and then I consider the derivative over x in both sides
and don't know how to follow, is this a dead end? What other method can I use?

Comment: Hint: $\dfrac{y'^2}{y^2-1}=\dfrac1x$.

Answer (score 1):

$$y'=\pm \frac{\sqrt{y^2-1}}{\sqrt{x}} \implies \int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{y^2-1}}=\pm \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}$$
Let $y=\sec z$, then
$$\int \sec z ~dz=\pm 2\sqrt{x}+C$$
$$\implies \ln(\sec z+\tan z)=\pm \sqrt{x}=C.$$
$$\ln[y+\sqrt{y^2-1}]=\pm 2 \sqrt{x}+C$$